# Drupal Form API - populate fields from Database

Tags: php, drupal, while-loop, form-api

Im looking to populate drupals form api fields with records from the database.

with:

```
    function mytopfive() {

  $form['mytop_header'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => t('<h2>Your favourite Jobs</h2>'),
  );


    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM topfive WHERE uid = 1 ORDER BY order_value ASC');

  while ($node = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $rid = $node->rid;
    $order = $node->order_value;
    $title= $node->title;
  $form['rid'][$node->rid] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 2,
    '#maxlength' => 1,
    '#default_value' => $rid,
  );

  $form['job_name'][$node->rid] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('To'),
    '#size' => 40,
    '#maxlength' => 42,
    '#value' => $title,
  );
  $form['job_order'][$node->rid] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 2,
    '#maxlength' => 1,
    '#default_value' => $order,
  );

  }

  $form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Submit'));



return $form;
}
```

it returns Array.

I feel the answer is a foreach loop.

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say: `"it returns Array"`... is that the output from an Echo, or the output to the drupal page?

if its the latter, you need to be calling this function from `drupal_get_form` in order to have the form rendered correctly. so in your case you need a menu item with `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form'` and `'page arguments' => array('mytopfive')`.

Let me know if that makes no sense :)

Comment: Spot on.. i just had a brain fart yesterday, was making more of it than what it was.. totally forgot to use drupal_get_form("form_name")